# docker compose: rebuild of one linked container breaks nginx's upstream

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose

I'm using `docker-compose` with "Docker for Mac" and I have two containers: one NGINX, one container serving a node-app on port 3000.

`docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
version: "2"

services:
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - api
  api:
    build: ./api
    volumes:
      - "./api:/opt/app"
```

In the NGINX's config I say:

```
upstream api {
  server api:3000;
}

server {
  # ....
  location ~ ^/api/?(.*) {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

    proxy_pass http://api;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

Now, when I change something in the node code and rebuild the container

```
$ docker-compose stop api && docker-compose up -d --build --no-deps api
```

the container is getting rebuilt and started. The problem is, that sometimes the internal IP of the container changes and NGINX won't know about that. Funny enough, when I go into the NGINX container and `ping api` I get the new IP address

```
$ ping api
PING api (172.19.0.3): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.19.0.3: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.236 ms
```

but NGINX logs still say

```
2016/10/20 14:20:53 [error] 9#9: *9 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.19.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /api/test HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.19.0.7:3000/api/test", host: "localhost"
```

where the upstream's `172.19.0.7` is still the old IP address.

PS: this doesn't happen every time I rebuild the container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because [Nginx caches the DNS response for upstream servers](https://tenzer.dk/nginx-with-dynamic-upstreams/) - in your workflow you're only restarting the app container, so Nginx doesn't reload and always uses its cached IP address for the `api` container.

When you run a new `api` container, as you've seen, it can have a different IP address so the cache in Nginx is not valid. The `ping` works because it doesn't cache Docker's DNS response.

Assuming this is just for dev and downtime isn't an issue, `docker-compose restart nginx` after you rebuild the app container will restart Nginx and clear the DNS cache.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. But how are e.g. docker cloud handling this "problem"? Haven't run into this when hosting a similar setup there ...

Comment: I don't think there's a functional difference in Docker Cloud - that's a management platform over remote Docker hosts, and the networking layer on the hosts is the same. If an app in your container queries DNS it will get a container's IP address and should respect the TTL Docker gives it. But if it doesn't, and caches the IP address indefinitely, there's not much the platform can do about that. There's a different approach to the Nginx setup in [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/240476/how-to-force-nginx-to-resolve-dns-of-a-dynamic-hostname-everytime-when-doing-p)

Comment: yup, also found this one: https://www.nginx.com/blog/dns-service-discovery-nginx-plus/

Comment: Late to the party, but `docker exec nginx-container nginx -s reload` gets the same result without restarting the container.